# Eliminar código Javascript no usado

Tags: javascript

tengo [este archivo javascript](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bystrokr/javascriptrarostackoverflow@main/plugins.bundle.js) que incluye **todos los plugins** que mi UI KIT basado en Bootstrap necesita. El arhivo pesa más de 2MB y mi web solo usa Jquery, SweetAlert, Toastr y Select2.

**¿Cómo puedo eliminar el resto de plugins que no ocupo de dicho archivo?**

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: puedes coger solo las librerias que necesitas en vez de un bundle

Comment: @NicolasOñate dentro de los archivos está la carpeta src con "bootstrap-multiselectsplitter" y "toastr" con archivos JS dentro de una carpeta build. Te refieres a esos?